# Mongo Db date time insertion

Tags: java, mongodb

I am newer in mongoDb trying to insert current date time using Java program. I am using joda library to to format the date into ISOdate format and want to store the current date and time as it is.But after doing insertion it is showing 1 hour delay time from my current time in data base.

Here is my code.

```
    DateTimeFormatter parser=ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();
    Instant inst=new Instant();
    DateTime result=parser.parseDateTime(parser.print(inst));
    dbObject.put(KeyConstants.CREATED_ON,result.toDate());
    dbObject.put(KeyConstants.UPDATED_ON,result.toDate());
    collection.insert(dbObject);
```

I am inserting current date and time :ISODate("2014-08-01T05:58:14Z")
But in data base it showing : ISODate("2014-08-01T06:58:14Z")

Comment: check the output of result.toDate(), it might be creating date with respect to Timezone

Comment: thanks : yeah it is creating but not storing the same in mongodb database storing 1 hour forward time into the data base

Comment: can u show the date created by result.toDate()

Answer (score 0):

Wahid, its happening because the date created out of

```
result.toDate()
```

is date with local timezone.

for example:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser=ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();      
DateTime result=parser.parseDateTime("2014-07-29T07:23:06");
System.out.println(result.toDate());
```

the result date is in

> Tue Jul 29 07:23:06 IST 2014

which is as per my local timezone.
And MongoDB stores date from epoch.

Add following code before result.toDate()

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

It will create UTC date.

You can refer [date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) document to know about dates in mongoDB
Hope so this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help Ninad,

I got sorted that problem the below code is inserting current date and time inside the data base as it is.

```
DateTimeFormatter parser=ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();
LocalDateTime dt=new LocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime result=parser.parseLocalDateTime(parser.print(dt));
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
dbObject.put("CREATED_ON",result.toDate());
dbObject.put("UPDATED_ON",result.toDate());
```

Regards :
Wahid